# Excel VBA Macro: Importing Workbooks, Copying Columns, And Looping Through Imported Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to create a copy tool for my Finance VBA course group that allows a user to import a series of workbooks, copy the same several columns from each workbook, and aggregate those columns into a single workbook.

For convenience, I have attached a set of sample import files and the desired output for those files.

It is also import to note that in Q1 and Q2, it is simply column B being copied. However, in Q3, it is column B and C being copied.

This is my current code below. Currently, it is only copying from 1 workbook and is simply repeating the same column throughout the rest of the workbook (though I am able to import more than 1 workbook). Any help at all would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
Sub import()
Dim OutputWorkbook As Workbook, InputWorkbook As Workbook, lInputWorkbookName As String, fDialog As Office.FileDialog, _
varFile As Variant, i As Long, sheet As Worksheet, cell As Range, _
Interest_Income As Range, temp As String, sourceColumn As Range,  targetColumn As Range _

ThisWorkbook.Activate

On Error GoTo handler

Set OutputWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Set targetColumn = OutputWorkbook.Sheets("Taxable Income Aggregate").Columns("C:XED")


ThisWorkbook.Activate

  ' Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

   With fDialog
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ' Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box
      .AllowMultiSelect = True

  .Title = "Import Your Workbooks"

  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel 97-2003 Workbook", "*.xls"
  .Filters.Add "Excel Workbook", "*.xlsx"
  .Filters.Add "Excel Binary Workbook", "*.xlsb"
  .Filters.Add "Macro-Enabled Workbook", "*.xlsm"
  .Filters.Add "All", "*.*"

  ' Show the dialog box.
      If .Show = True Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
            Workbooks.Open (varFile)
            lInputWorkbookName = Mid(varFile, InStrRev(varFile, "\") + 1)
            Set sheet = varFile.Sheets("Taxable Income Summary").Columns("B")
            For Each sheet In Workbooks(lInputWorkbookName).Sheets("Taxable Income Summary").Columns("B")
                sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn

                'For populating Taxable Income Aggregate
                'If sheet.Name Like "Taxable Income Summary" Then
                'End If
            Next

            Workbooks(lInputWorkbookName).Close
         Next

         OutputWorkbook.Sheets("Taxable Income Aggregate").Activate


         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
         Application.CutCopyMode = True
      Else
         MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
      End If
   End With

Exit Sub
handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Copy Tool -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-QauGO0OicTMEFEUlFvY28wNFU/view?usp=sharing

Input 3 -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QauGO0OicTUHJuMUs5UlVuU2s

Comment: If the **fDialog** is meant to allow the user to select multiple workbooks for import, why not a single `"All XL Workbooks", "*.xl*"` filter? Are there that many that they need to be split up into 4 groups (with a fifth for all)?

Comment: no - good idea. I'll limit this and cut down my code a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for the "Q3 is column B and C" which I don't get (how to know when to do it), this should work:

```
Sub import()
  On Error GoTo handler
  ThisWorkbook.Activate

  Dim OutputWorksheet As Object
  Set OutputWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Taxable Income Aggregate")

  Dim actCol As Long
  actCol = 3

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Import Your Workbooks"

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.xl*"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

    If .Show = True Then
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      Dim varFile As Variant    
      For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
        With Workbooks.Open(varFile)

          Dim xSheet As Object
          For Each xSheet In .Sheets
            If xSheet.Name Like "*Taxable Income Summary*" Then

              'Don't know how to ckeck for Q3
              'You still need to add that code

              xSheet.Columns("B").Copy OutputWorksheet.Column(actCol)
              actCol = actCol + 1
            End If
          Next
          .Close 0

        End With
      Next

      OutputWorksheet.Activate

    Else
      MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
    End If
  End With

  Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

  Exit Sub

handler:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
End Sub
```

`DisplayAlerts` and `ScreenUpdating` will automatically set to `True` (so there is no need to do it manualy) and `CutCopyMode` never need to be turned to "True" (actually: it can not be turned to `True` at all)

I also "skipped" some of your variables.

The target to copy to is set via `actCol`

The rest should be self explaining to you.

If you still have questions or trouble, just write a comment.

Comment: Dirk - this is great. that part that's missing was the other half of what I'm struggling with. since I'm a new user, I can't upload more than 2 links at a time- but what I meant is that, sometimes the import files need more than 1 column imported. sometimes it's 2, 3, or maybe 12 columns imported from the file from left to right. 

do you have any suggestion on this? let me know if you didn't understand. thanks so much for the help-

Comment: Can be done by something like `resize`... but as mentioned... how do you know when to import more than one column? There should be something to check for, if you know what I mean...

Comment: the information can be found on columns B through N or so. for instance, the attached file has 2 columns of information that need to be pulled in, but oftentimes there will just be 1 column or up to 12 columns. in the case of the attached file, the columns that are blank can be skipped - but I'm not sure of the code for this.

-how can I skip columns that are blank and only copy those columns (B:N) that include information?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it in this case. What do you think the code would be for that?